# Google analytic module - demographic track does not work

Tags: google-analytics

I am building a drupal 7 site, and using the [Google analytics module](https://drupal.org/project/google_analytics).

I installed it, and made the needed adjusments on my Google analytic account.

But, when I am on the Demographics tab on Google analytics, I can't see any data regarding the "overview", "Age" and "Gender". 
Note: "Track DoubleClick data" was always enabled.

In addition, I get the following message:

```
Some data in this report may have been removed when a threshold was applied
```

[Learn more](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2954071/?hl=en&utm_id=ad&authuser=0)

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to enable `Track DoubleClick data` under the Search and Advertising tab in the GA module settings.  You should also make sure your privacy policy is up to date with the correct info found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2819948).

Comment: I enabled "Track DoubleClick data" two weeks ago. I still do not see any data.. Maybe it is something else?

Comment: That's all I had to do on the Drupal side, on the analytics side I just had to skip the validation and make sure I wasn't using universal analytics.

Comment: what do you mean "Skip Validation"? why to skip and not to validate?